# Some Help to select some features from a vector layer

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, vector, html

I have a vector layer (kml) that has some point with scientific name of plants and animals, some description of the place where the people saw them and the coordinates.

Basically the table associated with the kml is something like this:

scientific name//description//lat//long

I'm working with OpenLayers, and I really appreciate if you can help to figure out about how to write the correct code:

application needed:

When I select a feature (from vector 3), All other features that share the same scientific name are highlighted too.

Here is my html code:

///////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBm6IRXcFDkoNusHY6tK_eJacDjMLJevyU&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var lat = 10.42500;
    var lon = -84.0160;
    var zoom = 15;
    var map; //complex object of type OpenLayers.Map
```

//---------------------------------------General map start----------------------------//

```
    function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
            controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()],
            maxResolution: 156543.0399,
            numZoomLevels: 20,
            units: 'm',
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        });
```

//---------------------------------------General Mapa end----------------------------//

//---------------------------------------APIs Start----------------------------//

```
        var capaGoogle = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", 
                             { numZoomLevels: 20 });
        var llave = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        var capaBing = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({ key: llave, type: "Aerial" });

        layerMapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Open Street Maps: Caminos");
```

//---------------------------------------APIs END----------------------------//

//--------------------------------Vector 1 start-----------------------------------//

```
        var contornoLaselva = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
            "Contorno La Selva",
            {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP(
                {
                    url: "La Selva_contorno_poli.kml",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML(
                    {
                        extractStyles: true,
                        extractAttributes: true,
                        maxDepth: 1

                    })
                })
            });
```

//--------------------------------Vector 1 end-----------------------------------------//

//--------------------------------Vector 2 Start--------------------------------------//

```
        var senderosLaSelva = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
            "Senderos de la Selva",
            {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP(
                {
                    url: "LaSelvaSenderos.kml",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML(
                    {
                        //extractStyles: true,
                        extractAttributes: true,
                        maxDepth: 1

                    })
                })
            });
```

//--------------------------------Vector 2 end---------------------------------------//

//--------------------------------Vector 2 stlye start-------------------------------//

```
      var senderosLaSelva_estilo = new OpenLayers.Style ({
          'strokeColor': '#000000',  //Define el color de la capa
          'strokeWidth': 1  //Grosor de la linea
          });

      var senderosLaSelva_estilo_mapa = new OpenLayers.StyleMap ({
          'default': senderosLaSelva_estilo
          });          
      senderosLaSelva.styleMap = senderosLaSelva_estilo_mapa;
```

//--------------------------------Vector 2 style end-------------------------------//

//--------------------------------Vector 3 and style start-------------------------//

```
        var ocurrenciasLaselva = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Especies Registradas La Selva",{           
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "Especies.kml",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                        extractStyles: true,
                        extractAttributes: true,
                        maxDepth: 1
                    })
                })
            })

 //-------------------Style------------------------//

        var ocurrenciasLaselva_estilo = new OpenLayers.Style({           
              'fill color': '#800080',
              'fill opacity': .5,
              'strokeColor': '#FFA500',
              'strokeWidth': 4,
              'pointRadius': 6                
              });

        var ocurrenciasLaselva_estilo_mapa = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
              'default': ocurrenciasLaselva_estilo
              });                 
        ocurrenciasLaselva.styleMap = ocurrenciasLaselva_estilo_mapa;
```

//--------------------------------Vector 3 and style end-------------------------//

//--------------------------------Vector 3 highlight start-----------------------//

```
        var report = function(e) {
            OpenLayers.Console.log(e.type, e.feature.id);
        };

        var sombreadoOcurrencias = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(ocurrenciasLaselva, {  
            hover: true,
            highlightOnly: true,
            renderIntent: "temporary",
            eventListeners: {
                beforefeaturehighlighted: report,
                featurehighlighted: report,
                featureunhighlighted: report
            }
        });
```

//--------------------------------Vector 3 highlight end-----------------------//

//--------------------------------Pop Ups for Vector 3 start--------------------//

```
        var controlSeleccion = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(ocurrenciasLaselva,
            {clickout: true}
        );

        function onPopupClose(evt) {
                  select.unselectAll();
        }

        function onFeatureSelect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        var content = "<h2>"+feature.attributes.name + "</h2>" + feature.attributes.description;
        if (content.search("<script") != -1) {
            content = "Content contained Javascript! Escaped content below.<br>" + content.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
        }
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
            content,
            null, true, onPopupClose);
        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
        }
        function onFeatureUnselect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        if(feature.popup) {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            delete feature.popup;
            }
        }

       ocurrenciasLaselva.events.on({
                  "featureselected": onFeatureSelect,
                  "featureunselected": onFeatureUnselect
       });
       selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(ocurrenciasLaselva);
```

//--------------------------------Pop Ups for Vector 3 end--------------------//

//--------------------------------Loader start---------------------------------------//

```
        map.addLayer(capaBing);
        map.addLayer(capaGoogle);    
        map.addLayer(layerMapnik);
        map.addLayer(contornoLaselva);            
        map.addLayer(senderosLaSelva);
        map.addLayer(ocurrenciasLaselva);

        map.addControl(sombreadoOcurrencias);
        map.addControl(controlSeleccion);
        sombreadoOcurrencias.activate();
        controlSeleccion.activate();             

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
```

//--------------------------------Loader end--------------------------------------//

```
        if (!map.getCenter()) {
            var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
        }
    }

</script>
```

init();

Answer (score 3):

Try using [getFeaturesByAttribute()](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getFeaturesByAttribute) instead of [getFeature()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getFeatureBy).

The former looks up using attributes (I think this is what you are trying to do), while the latter looks up using properties.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **getFeatureBy** method:

```
var lyr = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("test"); 

var ft = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10, 10),
           {scientific_name:'hydro'}); 

map.addLayer(lyr);
lyr.addFeatures([ft]);


var features = lyr.getFeatureBy('scientific_name', 'hydro');
```

and for highlighting them with scientific name you can delete all feature from map and then adding this new feature can help you.

Comment: Ok I'm trying the getFeatureBy looks like it is all I need thank you I'll update the post as soon as I finally resolve this!

Comment: ok , I tried but the map did not responde, it showed all the info already have but when I select one of my points nothing happen, I tryed to modify de getFeatureBy but it did not result, I was reading here http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/GetFeature-js.html but it think that I'm missing something!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using OpenStreetMaps (with OpenLayers 2.0 I think) and nothing of the above worked for me. After many hours of trial and error, I found [this page](https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=6972).

A for loop through all the features worked. Now I can move the feature (once called marker) and look at its position on the map.

```
for (var i = overlay.features.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
 var feature = overlay.features[i];
 console.log(feature.geometry.x + ";" + feature.geometry.y);
 //myLocation = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lat, lon).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
 myLocation = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
 feature.move(myLocation);
}
```

The marker goes in the wrong position, but at least it moves!